# All aboard the factorial train

Tags: code-golf, integer, combinatorics

## The system

Assume [the Earth is flat](https://xkcd.com/1318/) and that it extends infinitely in all directions. Now assume we have one infinitely long train railway and `n` trains in that railway. *All* trains have different speeds and *all* trains are going in the same direction. When a faster train reaches a slower train, the two trains connect (becoming a single train) and the new train keeps going at the speed with which the slower train was going.

E.g., if we have two trains, one going at speed 1 and another at speed 9, the lines below "simulate" what would happen on the railway:

```
9               1
         9       1
                 11
                  11
                   11
```

whereas if the trains start in a different order, we'd have

```
1 9
 1         9
  1                 9
   1                          9
etc...
```

With that being said, given a train/position/speed configuration there comes a time when no more connections will be made and the number of trains on the railway stays constant.

## Task

Given the number `n` of trains in the railway, your task is to compute the *total* number of trains there will be on the railway, after all the connections have been made, summing over all `n!` possible arrangements of the `n` trains.

A possible algorithm would be:

- Start counter at 0
- Go over all possible permutations of the train speeds

  - Simulate all the connections for this permutation
  - Add the total number of remaining trains to the counter
- Return the counter

**Note** that you can assume the train speeds are whatever `n` distinct numbers that you see fit, what really matters is the relationships between train speeds, not the magnitudes of the differences in speeds.

## Input

You must take `n`, a positive integer, as input.

## Output

An integer representing the total number of trains that there will be on the railway, summed over all possible permutations of the trains.

## Test cases

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 3
3 -> 11
4 -> 50
5 -> 274
6 -> 1764
7 -> 13068
8 -> 109584
9 -> 1026576
10 -> 10628640
11 -> 120543840
12 -> 1486442880
13 -> 19802759040
14 -> 283465647360
15 -> 4339163001600
16 -> 70734282393600
17 -> 1223405590579200
18 -> 22376988058521600
19 -> 431565146817638400
20 -> 8752948036761600000
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it! If you dislike this challenge, please give me your feedback. Happy golfing!

Comment: This is [A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman OEIS, _removing the fun of all sequence-related challenges since God knows when_

Comment: always check OEIS before you post...

Comment: Interestingly, whether the trains take the speed of the slower or the faster one when they collide doesn't actually change the final answer, though I don't have a rigorous proof for this (yet).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I guess the explanation [on my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201085/75323) is a possible way to prove; the explanation can be perfectly adapted to the case where the faster trains stay fast :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
!:RS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/RKij4////pgA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/RKij4f9DRPYfbHzWtcf//38gAAA).

#### How?

When we introduce an \$n^{\text{th}}\$ train it allows:

- \$(n-1)!\$ states - by being placed behind none of the \$n-1\$ existing trains and being faster than all of them.
- all the previous end states, each in \$n\$ different ways - by being placed behind at least one existing train and being faster than \$[0,n-1]\$ of the \$n-1\$ existing trains

We know \$a(1) = 1\$ so...

```
n  a(n) 
1  1
2  1! + 1*2
3  2! + 1!*3 + 1*2*3
4  3! + 2!*4 + 1!*3*4 + 1*2*3*4
5  4! + 3!*5 + 2!*4*5 + 1!*3*4*5 + 1*2*3*4*5
... etc
```

Which is:

```
n  a(n) 
1  1
2  1 + 2
3  1*2 + 1* 3 + 2*3
4  1*2*3 + 1*2* 4 + 1* 3*4 + 2*3*4
5  1*2*3*4 + 1*2*3* 5 + 1*2* 4*5 + 1* 3*4*5 + 2*3*4*5
...
n  n!/n + n!/(n-1) + n!/(n-2) + ... + n!/1
```

Hence the code:

```
!:RS - integer, n
!    - (n) factorial      n!
  R  - range (n)          [1,...,n-2,n-1,n]
 :   - integer division   [n!/1,...,n!/(n-2),n!/(n-1),n!/n]
   S - sum                a(n)
```

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: me: thinks i did something in jelly // jonathan allan: hello

Comment: Still submitted a five when there was a four :p

Comment: Huh, I had been wondering which algorithm you were using, but because you hadn't added your explanation at the time I had to go and rediscover it for myself...

Comment: @RGS golfing languages...

Comment: @htmlcoderexe I am pretty sure RGS was not refering to the terseness of the language but rather the underlying method (which I had not described at the time)

Comment: @htmlcoderexe Please refer to JonathanAllan's comment above mine :D I have submitted a couple of Jelly answers myself, but I am not very accustomed to its built-ins, so even a short answer like this 4-byter can throw me off... That was what I was referring to :)

Comment: This stuff is literal Chinese for me - I've always wondered if a unified score system was possible based on some kind of instructions or something

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n>1?(n+--n)*f(n)-n*n*f(n-1):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZNCoMwEAbQq8wyozNC6k9V0B5EXAQ1YtEvoqXXT@lbvbf7unu6tvOjCPMSo@/Q9ejtyyBVBSfegBUJ/lHLLeIUcId9yfawmsEKPYRyoUKoFKqEnkK1UDNmhzuNZ44/)

This is an implementation of the recurrence relation:

$$\cases{
a(0)=0\\
a(1)=1\\
a(n) = a(n-1) \times (2n - 1) - a(n-2) \times (n - 1)^2,\:n>1}$$

Comment: I'm sorry for the error in editing, I thought I had checked and assumed it was a bug (which was probably silly).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman No worries! I was just a bit puzzled by the reason for changing it.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
+/!÷⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBG19xcPbH/VuBvIOrVAAMhSMDAA)

Calculates the sum of (`+/`) the factorial of \$n\$ (`!`) divided by (`÷`) the range 1 to \$n\$ (`⍳`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
Tr[#!/Range@#]&
```

*-1 byte from @Greg Martin*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6QoWllRPygxLz3VQTlW7X9AUWZeiYK@Q7q@A0TQyOD/fwA)

Comment: well done beating the builtin `Abs@StirlingS1[#+1,2]&`

Comment: @GregMartin I think now I'm done ;)

Comment: I think you can shave one more byte with `Tr[#!/Range@#]&` :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
!IL÷O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f0dPn8Hb///9NAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and n*f(n-1)+math.factorial(n-1)
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVLLahwxELzrKzo67Sb2ovfDYEMOySfkFAiKZ8Yr0GqGkdYQwn77Ri0RPBd1VbWqS81sf@p5zfJ@X55TuPyeAuSnDCFPkD8vh/zIj18uoZ5PS3it6x5D6hyJl23dK6B0r3Opv15DmQs8A6WUw@MLcCLwkER2xInCUzOi8RRWEdMFaxSxvZLMOOJ6ybx2ivhRC6OtIZwNZIQzihE@hgimlXSI@zSumqiEc40Yc71jwmrPsKUnEE4qo42y0jSqh1FSem4kY9ywxvVcllnZjIT0spMjohBSMd3stPUC6R63sdb4NlQ7LYaHH75cG82Vce2VmJIR0V/hrBZeOSaNNdjfvrY2QpZ1B1wmxAwfSz2VLcV6oD8zPT4RgPwA67W2VWPLfxFt6RHVJsRcDxnBMhqXgeIyiE@jo5XdD2APsczwI6Tr/G3f1/2w0O8hpnkaaTAF/M23Byjn9ZomeIvvjWj3b/1HeQsI0frWIsypzGi77TiEfk3pw6XAFkqZpxM93v8B)

Implements the recurrence relation given by

$$\begin{cases}a(n) = n\times a(n-1) + (n-1)! \\
a(0) = 0 \end{cases}$$

**How**: If you have \$n\$ trains on the railway, consider removing the faster one from the railway and take the \$(n-1)!\$ permutations of the remaining \$n-1\$ trains. For each permutation of the \$n-1\$ trains, there are \$n\$ places where you can put the \$n\$th train, the fastest one.

- If you put it in the front, then the connections made by the other \$n-1\$ trains remain exactly the same, and those never catch up with the faster train. So placing it in the front adds a new train to the total sum.
- If you put it in any other of the \$n - 1\$ positions, it will just connect to the train in front and then we are back at the case when we had \$n - 1\$ trains on the railway, so the total number of trains stays the same.

Comment: You beat me to it! Took me a while to figure out this recurrent relation. I also missed that Python has a factorial function :(

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>50</s>  49 bytes

-1 thanks to Surculose Sputum (using walrus in 3.8 to save some `~-`s)

```python
f=lambda n:n>1and(2*n-1)*f(n:=n-1)-n*n*f(n-1)or n
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsMwEEP3fsVt8ZmkYHcpB8m/uCRuA41i3FtKyLe7djVITyClr7523O4plxLHd9gecyAIJhcwG28xOLbRQMZGAyxaq7hnQonVdfkoraAc8FyM68k7lgtVpbxCTXfI5E@h4@yudb8FNe3SU/wnM5cf)**

---

A **52** using a different approach:

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n*k and~-n*f(n-1,k)+f(n-1,k-1)or n==k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBDsIgFET3nuLvyq9gAksSvAumRRvstMG/aZp6dUTj28xbzFs3eSxwtabwjPNtiASdg/PoM0UMb4M@KRirM5//YiwvhRBCrqmJjC@hCVQi7qOympxlf6LGWiaI6nZ/dYen/egu7T9HUd9EU/otM9cP)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsMwEEP3fsVt8ZmkYHcpB8m/uCRuA41i3FtKyLe7djVITyClr7523O4plxLHd9gecyAIJhcwG28xOLbRQMZGAyxaq7hnQonVdfkoraAc8FyM68k7lgtVpbxCTXfI5E@h4@yudb8FNe3SU/wnM5cf) using walrus operator

Comment: @SurculoseSputum thanks!

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I keep seeing your username and thinking it says "Sucralose Spectrum". I need to go to bed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>57</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan !*

```python
i=x=0
f=1
exec"i+=1;x=i*x+f;f*=i;"*input()
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NDoMgEITvPMWGXvCnSfGo2b4LVdBN2sUQjPTpqWLn@GW@zKzfuHju8ugni1LKTJjwIRxqYZMdJTWoh4RUp8YNrkYaZE28blFVYg3EEVI@NOF8AAZiCIZnq3QLna56AUduEGiGvwTRQ7BxCwxxsReF3cJuOJZ2Ifg2n9dkeuDCriFu5f0p20LOb@r8XOUf)

---

**If the sequence is 0-indexed, we can cut down 2 more bytes**

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
i=x=f=1
exec"i+=1;x=i*x+f;f*=i;"*input()
print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5LDoMwDET3OYWVbvh1AUuQuUsKCVhqHRQZkZ4@hdBZPs3TzPaV1XOXJj9b1FonwogOW2WjnTTV2A4RqYq1G1yFNOiKeNulKNUWiAViOiXlfAAGYgiGF1t0bdkrOPOAQAv8DRAPwcoeGGS1N4XDwmFYcjsTfJvPazY9cGb3Cjf6Oeomk@tYcd0t0w8)

---

**How:**
This solution uses the `exec` trick, which repeats the code `n` times, then `exec` the repeated code.

`f` is the current factorial.
`x` (the solution function) is defined by the recurrent relation:
$$x(i)=ix(i-1)+(i-1)!$$
and
$$x(0)=0$$

[@RGS's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201085/92237) has a really nice explanation for this formula.

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU5LDsIgEN1zikk3fOpCuiyZm7jBFnQSBUIxwdNji4lxdu8/6V3uMUxtiatDzvmlEVY8M4@aueqWgUbUpiKpOnrjFZIZFIX0KkKylCkUqG3PMR8zFLcVoADZhpsT@gSTljOD/XoCH/Z5Xe3cfZ3@FvzgMSiOT@Sfynn7AA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
≔…·¹ＮθＩΣ÷Πθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DMy85p7Q4syw1KDEvPVXDUEfBM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU1NHoVDTmiugKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0F6ipxCWzLDMlVSOgKD@lNLlEoxCsEAis//@3/K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔…·¹Ｎθ
```

Create a range from `1` to `n`.

```
    θ   Range `1`..`n`
   Π    Product i.e. `n!`
  ÷     Vectorised divide by
     θ  Range `1`..`n`
 Σ      Sum
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{sum [*]($_)X/$_}o^*+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU/LSkNRDNznK86iiFa85p0cRL9DEC0u7Kql0uKiiN9@PY9skpmEmcn31/ng6/Fabvbluay/l59jedu@3252d6@Pm93f6WN7T@sTXD6vZWk3@9O50LIwrlQeXgoB9yYgAxFo74ZgvXMo@FiEK8SYBD0hx4jVUqHOmd3CgXAi53RFoGnCaCrZ8XAjbUvlzEZM35rIYRX7yUjAKermGuKNGmFUpJILIjk2buQKDGlCLFUGOSMyi6I1OYvKnR5xGxtem6ml8dSoU5fMjdSzfdlTIvD4IsO4aqJ4eL9v9Q8)

Returns the sum of the factorial of \$n\$ divided by the range 1 to \$n\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `j`, <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

After scanning through the source, I realized an undocumented feature - the `j` flag can actually sum the output at the end!

```
7Uëÿ
```

Uncompressed:

```
*rak/
```

### Explanation

```
*r     % Reduce via multiplication
       % (Contains implicit range)
  ak   % Range from input to 1
    /  % Division (integer division when
       % none of the operands are floating-points)
Flag:j % Sum the resulting list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
1#.!%1+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1FFUNtTP1/mtyKXClJmfkK2hYp2kqqNkpGCpoK2TqWUAEDQ2sFdKAZAWUawrmmkK5RmBZI4OK/wA)

```
1#.           the sum of (by conversion to base 1)
   !          n factorial
    %         divided by
     1+i.     the list 1..n
```

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
+/*/'1+&:'~=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KW19LX91QW81Kvc72f5qC6X8A)

Comment: this one was hard to beat: `{+/*/'1+&:'~=x}` or `+/*/'1+&:'~=:`

Comment: actually, in oK it also works without the final `:`

Comment: @ngn Very nice use of the identity matrix! (I forgot about the monadic use of `=`) Thanks for your lesson!

Comment: @ngn I tried [a different approach](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWltfS1/dULsiTl2xovZ/moLpfwA)

Comment: .. and i forgot oK has `atom^` :) one of the things i tried was `a^/:a:1+!x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
a 0=0
a n=n*a(n-1)+product[1..n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1HBwNaAK1EhzzZPK1EjT9dQU7ugKD@lNLkk2lBPD8iP/Z@bmJlnW1CUmVeikqhg@h8A)

This implements the [OEIS definition](https://oeis.org/A000254).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n>1?(n+n--)*f(n)-n*n*f(n-1):n;}
```

Port of Jonathan Allan's Python 3.8 answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDsIwDET3fIVVCclu8BBGQuFHWFCqIA9cUYVYqn57cLjlPd1d0WcprVWGbJhwTTdGhKqMvVKM6KJJzsh7M3zo9TDwd7FZwhbIU5eV@2A0UcqOi/PkEqP8Dz3v1S@Vh8N8x3CkyiaSw95@)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Œ!«\€Q€FL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMVDq2MeNa0JBGI3n////1sAAA)

this is the non-smart trivial approach

## Explanation

Observe that if we have a list of trains' speeds, moving left, then we can cumulatively reduce by minimum to get the final list of trains' speeds.

```
Œ!«\€Q€FL  Main Link
Œ!         all permutations (defaults over a range)
    €      For each permutation
   \       Cumulatively reduce by
  «        minimum
      €    For each permutation
     Q     remove duplicate values
       F   join all of the trains (flatten)
        L  and get the final length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆÊ/°X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=xsovsFg&input=MjA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>70</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>64</s></sup> 63 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!

```c
l;c;i;t;f(n){l=0;for(c=i=1;i<n;l=c,c=t)t=-l*i*i+c*(i+++i);n=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY5LCoNAEET3nqIRhPmJMxo/oZ2cJJvQYmgwnSDuxLObcVOPWryiqHwTneeChIwbzkr0vkSP83dVFDkG5FFwieQobnqL5WLYsCWj2FrLGiUSHufnxaL0nl0aywaSRBlDQGtFQ2UgOGgchITWO6j7Wyp9d2XjuyHB39vhqr7u2r4DU2W/NS3NKi8mKB9QTE/JHYiD66PG7Dj/)

Uses [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s [formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201081/9481).

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY5LCoNAEET3nqIRhPmJMxo/oZ2cJJvQYmgwnSDuxLObcVOPWryiqHwTneeChIwbzkr0vkSP83dVFDkG5FFwieQobnqL5WLYsCWj2FrLGiUSHufnxaL0nl0aywaSRBlDQGtFQ2UgOGgchITWO6j7Wyp9d2XjuyHB39vhqr7u2r4DU2W/NS3NKi8mKB9QTE/JHYiD66PG7Dj/) by rearranging the operations a bit

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Nice refactor - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 70 bytes

```lisp
(λ(x)(let([a(range 1(+ 1 x))])(apply +(map(λ(y)(/(apply * a)y))a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcwxDsIwFAPQvaewxGLTAYXrIIYvSFDVUEWhQ3M27sCVQoKoN1tPznab/VoP0ZYH8q8MvPswLR6h8vPmJka/8mLMzXg4jnDYpKtoKcWCkU9LnRbx9N@OMBXJ1FI1tM/plaIVdIuA/Qxn18UX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 61 bytes

```
: f ( n -- n ) [1,b] dup [ product ] dip [ / ] with map sum ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY27DsIwFEN3vsIjSKQ8xnQHdemCmKIOoU0hor0NyY0QXx9CxGIdy7I96p4Xn66Xpj1LPI0nM2HW/ChSeU13ExDMKxrqMzlvmD/OW2LUq6aVOJUFqyfBXltKEiPWIAiRZQN12N46DNFB5fIyxJ6Rvf35Xaa3LV8OIc6o03H/b6g805WgSl8)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
╒k!╠Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##BcFLDYAwFEXB/XGBg96W/uSwARIgbFBC0j0JfhBRI4@ZY7rW5dxns97ubejt@V4z4QmMRBKZQkUOCXkU0IgiSiijgire/Q)

Or

```
!k╒/Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##BcFLDYAwFEXB/XGBAnr7rxw2lAQIG5SQoAA/iMDIY2afzqUf22w2rN99je9jJjyBSCJTqDTkkJBHAUWUUEYFVdTw7gc)

**Explanation:**

```python
╒      # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 k!    # Push the input-integer again, and pop and push its factorial
   ╠   # Divide the factorial by each value in the list (b/a builtin)
    Σ  # And sum that list
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)

!      # Push the factorial of the (implicit) input-integer
 k╒    # Push the input-integer again, and pop and push a list in the range [1, input]
   /   # Divide the factorial by each value in the list
    Σ  # And sum that list
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```